# How to rewrite this lines of code in a more "elegant" way?

Tags: java, for-loop, int

So I have this lines of code and I'm trying to find a way to write them in a more elegant way:

```
         int randomHints1 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints2 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints3 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints4 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints5 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints6 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints7 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints8 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints9 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
         int randomHints10 = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
```

I'm guessing a "for loop" method would be the answer, but I can't find a way to resolve this.
Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int[] randomHints = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<randomHints.length;i++)
    randomHints[i] = hintsRandom.nextInt(1100) + 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of an array

```
int[] randomHints = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < randomHints.length; i++) {
    randomHints[i] = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200 - 100) + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be more elegant if you would use an array:

```
int[] randomHints = new int[10];
...
for(int i = 0;i<randomHints.length;i++) {
    randomHints[i] = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200-100) + 100;
}
```

ps.: if you need a dynamic amount of random numbers you could use an arraylist

Answer (score 1):

My answer is basically the same as others, using an array and iteration, but I use Java 8 streams to write it in one line. I think it's more elegant.

```
int[] randomHints = new int[10];
Arrays.stream(randomHints).forEach(i -> randomHints[i] = hintsRandom.nextInt(1200 - 100) + 100);
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] randomHints = IntStream.generate(() -> 100 + hitsRandom.nextInt(1100)).limit(10).toArray();
```